# Ionic/Phonegap: how can I OAuth with my backend server using Google etc?

Tags: cordova, google-oauth, ionic-framework

I have a webserver that needs to contain credentials for the user, so it can fetch emails in the background. However, I would like to authenticate my mobile client with this server using Google. On the web, the user signs in/up using Google, and then the session infra authenticates every subsequent request.

On the mobile, how can I make authenticated requests with my backend server? Because on the mobile, the user is usually authenticated at install-time, and never afterwards. Also, the refresh_token really needs to be on the server, but the mobile client should not need to authenticate every so often as is the common mobile paradigm. The sign up could happen either on mobile or the web.

Thanks!